# Custom ApiExplorer with Namespace based ApiControllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, documentation, asp.net-apicontroller, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I'm trying to add API documentation at my backend system.
Default ApiExplorer and Help page worked absolutely great until the moment I introduced versions to my Api Controllers.

In order to add versions I created sub folders under the Controllers folder:

- v1
- v2
- v3

and have version based Api Controllers there. In order to have my Api discoverable I have to rewrite DefaultHttpControllerSelector to take into account namespaces provided by any client and map them to right controllers:

- http://backend.com/api/v1/controller/action
- http://backend.com/api/v2/controller/action

This have broken my default ApiExplorer and the following property returns ZERO api descriptions

```
Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions
```

How can I customize existent ApiExplorer and help him to find my Api Controllers and not to rewrite whole ApiExplorer implementation. I really need just to show where to find my Api Controllers.

Please advise.

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing... Any chance you figured out how to implement this?

Comment: I answered your question below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out that there is nothing to do with ApiExplorer. As instead you should modify your namespace based controller selector:

```
NamespaceHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
//...
    public override IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping() 
    {
        var mapping = base.GetControllerMapping();
        mapping["User"] = new HttpControllerDescriptor
        {
            Configuration = _httpConfig,
            ControllerName = "User",
            ControllerType = typeof(UserController)
        };
        //...
        return mapping;
    }
    //...  }
```

That is. After that default ApiExplorer will find you  controllers and fetch all the actions.

Answer (score 8):

I will show you a way to do that. This code is just for learning. Here I not talking about design and best practices, so feel free to change anything you want.

Well, You must follow the next steps:

**1) Create a custom ApiExplorer:**

```
public class MyApiExplorer: ApiExplorer
{
    private readonly string _version;

    public MyApiExplorer(string version) : base(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
        _version = version != null ? version.ToUpperInvariant() : "V1";

        foreach(var apiDescription in ApiDescriptions)
        {
            apiDescription.RelativePath = apiDescription.RelativePath.Replace("{version}", _version);
        }

    }

    public override bool ShouldExploreController(string controllerVariableValue, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        IHttpRoute route)
    {
        return controllerDescriptor.ControllerType.FullName.Contains(_version);
    }
```

}

> a) In the constructor _version will be converted to upperCase (just in
>   case it will be passed as lowerCase) but if it is null then it will
>   take V1 as default. Then change relative path to show specific version
>   instead of {version}.
>
> b) ShouldExploreController (in short words)
>   decide if specific controller is taken to show in documentation. In
>   this case we will only show controllers that its type full name contains
>   choosed version.

**2) Go to HelpController class and change Index method like this:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string version)
{
    //...

    Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IApiExplorer), new MyApiExplorer(version));

    return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
}
```

> We are replacing current ApiExplorer by our own in order to be
>   returned when call to Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer()

Now you can use this .../help?version=v1 or .../help?version=v2 or .../help?version=v3 and you will get specific api controller documentation.

Comment: Solid.  Thanks for the instruction!

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off putting Configuration.Services.Replace in a static ctor for HelpController?  Otherwise, this will be called every single time.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem recently, and solved mine with this:
2 LOC:

```
public class VersionControllerSelector : IHttpControllerSelector
```

to

```
public class VersionControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
```

...and...

```
public VersionControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
```

to

```
public VersionControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config) : base(config)
```